# Why isn't my shortcut for accessing desktop not working?

Tags: macos, shortcut, desktop

I'm using a Macbook Pro and I just upgraded to Mac Sierra.  I wanted to see if there was a keyboard shortcut for accessing my Desktop (and the icons that are on it) so I read this article -- http://www.noproblemmac.com/blog/2015/05/21/how-to-always-get-to-your-macs-desktop/ , and tried the shortcuts provided.  Specifically, Fn + F11 or Command + F3 (Mission control key?) but neither combination works.

How do I enable keyboard shortcuts for the desktop or what are the proper key sto press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you should use the Fn key depends on whether you have enabled "Use F1, F2 etc. keys as standard function keys" in Keyboard preferences. Try just pressing F11, without pressing Fn. And then look in the Mission Control system preference pane and see what key is assigned to Show Desktop.

Comment: OH yeah, I was overcompicating it.  Press F11 worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset that.

Go to:

System Preferences
→ Keyboard
→ Shortcuts
→ Mission Control
→ Show Desktop
→ Click on right command (F11)
→ Press Command + D

I prefer `Command + D` because reminds me Windows but you can setup `Command + F3` or whatever other combination you like.